# how to know if project uses OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I'm creating static lib for ios projects.
I'm making screenshots in thi library. If the project uses openGL i have another function to make screenshot.
So my question is how to detect if projects uses opengl from my library.
Is it a way to check if project has opengl framework?

Thank you

UPDATED:
Actually i need to know only one thing - how to make this function glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer); using introspection?

Answer (score 0):

We can tell if something is linked using introspection, picking a symbol known to be present only in that library.  For example, if GLKit is linked, we can check for EAGLContext this way:

```
+ (BOOL)glkIsLinked {

    return NSClassFromString(@"EAGLContext") != nil;
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to know only one thing - how to make this function glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer); using introspection?